# Error in parsebinary function for converting int8 to an image file

Tags: java, mysql, matlab, parsing, jdbc

I'm trying to convert the data from mysql database to an image file using JDBC in Matlab. Now, the problem lies in converting the int8 data type to PNG. I keep getting an error in parsebinary function.

Here's the code:

```
[conn] = get_connection();
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat','cellarray')
if isopen(conn)
query = 'SELECT img_id, img, img_grp FROM dataset WHERE img_grp = 0';
curs = exec(conn, query);
curs = fetch(curs);
curs.Data
img = curs.Data{1,2};
cd 'C:\Users\Inspiron 14\Desktop\testmatlabodbc'
parsebinary(img, 'PNG');
end
close(curs)
close(conn)
```

Here's the error message I'm seeing:

```
Error using imread>get_format_info (line 491)
Unable to determine the file format.

Error in imread (line 354)
        fmt_s = get_format_info(fullname);

Error in parsebinary (line 74)
    [x,map] = imread(['testfile.' lower(f)]);

Error in test1 (line 10)
    parsebinary(img, 'PNG');
```

Comment: So what's your question? `imread` looks for 'testfile.png' but can't determine its format. Do you have this file? Is it a correct PNG file? What is `parsebinary`? I don't think this is a standard function. Is it this? https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/retrieve-image-data-types.html

Comment: I'm passing the img variable as the binary object in the parsebinary. My question is how to correctly display img variable as an image type. I based my code in the link that you gave.

Comment: That `parsebin` function tries to decode a PNG file that is in memory, by writing the data to file and reading it back as if it were a PNG file. Is that the data you pass to this function? Or do you have raw `uint8` values that directly represent an image?

Comment: The img variable is an int8 value that I directly accessed from MySQL database. The int8 value is originally a blob data type which I'm trying to convert to an image type to be processed in the image processing.

Comment: Sure, but is it PNG encoded image data (with PNG header and all the PNG tags and so on)? Obviously it's not, or the function wouldn't give that error message. Is it a raw pixel stream, or is encoded in some other way? If you don't know what data this is, there is no hope of decoding it.